# What can cause Invalid address 0xda9739b8 passed to free: value not allocated?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, fatal-error

I am trying in retrieving and writing signal from thirty-part machine (EEG headset) into file.csv through bluetooth. Now, i connect successfully with headset but while recording signal i met a fatal signal that i had no idea about.

Here is the code i possiply think might be the problem:

```
IEE_DataChannel_t[] Channel_list;
String[] Name_Channel = {"AF3","T7","Pz","T8","AF4"};
```

and the function to retrieve data

```
        case 2:
            if(bp_writer == null) return;
            for(int i=0; i < Channel_list.length; i++)
            {
                SWIGTYPE_p_double ptheta = edkJava.new_double_p();
                SWIGTYPE_p_double palpha = edkJava.new_double_p();
                SWIGTYPE_p_double plow_beta = edkJava.new_double_p();
                SWIGTYPE_p_double phigh_beta = edkJava.new_double_p();
                SWIGTYPE_p_double pgamma = edkJava.new_double_p();
                int result = -1;
                result = edkJava.IEE_GetAverageBandPowers(userId, Channel_list[i], ptheta, palpha, plow_beta, phigh_beta, pgamma);
                if(result == edkJava.EDK_OK){
                    Log.e("FFT", "GetAverageBandPowers");
                    try {
                        bp_writer.write(Name_Channel[i] + ",");
                        addData(edkJava.double_p_value(ptheta));
                        addData(edkJava.double_p_value(palpha));
                        addData(edkJava.double_p_value(plow_beta));
                        addData(edkJava.double_p_value(phigh_beta));
                        addData(edkJava.double_p_value(pgamma));
                        bp_writer.newLine();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                edkJava.delete_double_p(ptheta);
                edkJava.delete_double_p(palpha);
                edkJava.delete_double_p(plow_beta);
                edkJava.delete_double_p(phigh_beta);
                edkJava.delete_double_p(pgamma);
            }
            break;
        }

    }

};
```

there is the function for add data and set the file.csv:

```
private void setDataFile() {
    try {
        String eeg_header = "Channel , Theta ,Alpha ,Low beta ,High beta , Gamma ";
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String file_path = root.getAbsolutePath()+ "/FFTSample/";
        File folder=new File(file_path);
        if(!folder.exists())
        {
            folder.mkdirs();
        }
        bp_writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file_path+"bandpowerValue.csv"));
        bp_writer.write(eeg_header);
        bp_writer.newLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("","Exception"+ e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void addData(double data) {

    if (bp_writer == null) {
        return;
    }

        String input = "";
            input += (String.valueOf(data) + ",");
        try {
            bp_writer.write(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

It added user successfully, but when started recording, i met

```
A/libc: Invalid address 0xda9739b8 passed to free: value not allocated 
A/libc: Invalid address 0xda973068 passed to free: value not allocated 
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3969 (motiv.fftsample) 
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3938 (motiv.fftsample) 
I/libc: Another thread contacted debuggerd first; not contacting debuggerd.
```

So, how do i track errors, i am just a beginner on building app. Thanks

Comment: Please read this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then follow it and edit your question :) I don't believe it is necessary to provide us with such an extensive amount of the code to read. In other words: remove **really everything** which is not needed to reproduce your error. Maybe during the process you will *yourself* find the cause of your problem, or at least you will make the SO community more keen to solve *your* problem.

Comment: thanks, there is my first time posting the issue on. I updated it, can u review for me @HonzaZidek

Comment: In this situation, I would first check for a Java stacktrace. Now, this looks like a problem on the JNI side, so you might not have one. In that case, my approach would be to bracket the error using a large number of `Log.d()` calls (this, in order to isolate the line on which this is happening).

Comment: And oh my gosh why is there more than one thread here... your concurrency scheme is another possible source of errors...

Comment: @greeble31, i am still working on, using `Thread.activeCount()` and counting how many threads. It is 0 first and when i start  the retrieve and write function, then it is 1 and meet the fatal signal

Comment: for clearly, i create 1 thread which have 3 cases, if 2 first cases are checked, until i click Start button, the case 3 will run. and then i meet the problem there.

Comment: @NhatKhangTruongKhanh I trust that you can keep track of the threads _you've_ started; maybe it is your library (edkJava) creating the threads. If that's the case, maybe the multiple threads are nothing to be worried about, but I'm not so sure. What _is_ edkJava, anyway? Your question doesn't say.

Comment: @NhatKhangTruongKhanh You removed a lot of code (good!), but you did not provided a really **minimal** (why do we have to bother with all your alfas, betas, gamas and deltas?), **reproducible** (we cannot run your code, there are mysterious classes, unnecessary `case 2` of some mysterious `switch` etc.), **comprehensible**. Remove **really all** (ALL!) the code which is unnecessary for reproducing the error. Do it first of all **for yourself** - you need to **isolate the error**!

Comment: @NhatKhangTruongKhanh I see in your edit history that you are calling `new Thread()`. Let me give you some advice: You want to be 100% sure that not more than 1 of those threads is running at a time. I mean, verify it with `Log.d()` statements; don't just attempt to draw conclusions by examining the code.